# Use one column of a groupby to create X new columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've this dataframe `df`:

```
                     date dir
0     2018-01-23 11:39:41  O1
1     2018-01-23 12:47:58  E0
2     2018-01-23 13:01:19  O1
3     2018-01-23 13:01:21  O1
4     2018-01-23 13:06:06  O1
5     2018-01-23 13:32:55  O1
6     2018-01-23 13:33:56  O1
7     2018-01-23 13:33:58  O1
8     2018-01-23 13:46:47  E0
9     2018-01-23 14:04:01  E0
10    2018-01-23 14:04:39  O1
11    2018-01-23 14:09:16  E0
12    2018-01-23 14:17:46  E0
...
```

I want to count the number of occurence by `date` (hourly) and by `dir`(direction).
There is two different directions: `E0` and `O1`.

So I've done that:

```
df = df.groupby(['dir',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='H')]).size()
```

Of course I got something like that:

```
dir  date               
E0   2018-01-23 12:00:00     1
     2018-01-23 13:00:00     1
     2018-01-23 14:00:00     5
...
O1   2018-05-21 19:00:00     1
     2018-05-21 20:00:00     1
     2018-05-22 06:00:00     2
...
```

But I would like to create a new column for each distinct direction:

```
                date    E0 O1
 2018-05-21 19:00:00     1  0
 2018-05-21 20:00:00     1  2
 2018-05-22 06:00:00     2  0
...
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by first level and parameter `fill_value` for replace new `NaN`s values for non exist combinations `dir` and `date`s:

```
df = df.groupby(['dir',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='H')]).size().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
print (df)
dir                  E0  O1
date                       
2018-01-23 11:00:00   0   1
2018-01-23 12:00:00   1   0
2018-01-23 13:00:00   1   6
2018-01-23 14:00:00   3   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be using [pd.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(index= ['date'], columns='dir', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0).resample('1H').sum()
```